# How to get a specific value in C# ListBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, filter, listbox, listboxitem

Hello i wanna get all the values after the last square bracket ']'  so lets say the following values are in my ListBox

```
[Database]ColumnName
[Firefox]Browser
[Program]VisualStudio
[SQL]SQLSERVER
```

and i wanna see

```
ColumnName
Browser
VisualStudio
SQLSERVER
```

my code

```
foreach (var s in ListBox1.Items)
{
    if (s.Equals("]") == true)
    {
        var desc = s.Equals("]");
        ListBox2.items.add(desc)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `split` and `last`

```
 foreach (var s in ListBox1.Items)
 {
      var desc = s.ToString().Split("]").Last();
      ListBox2.Items.Add(desc);
 }
```

this way, your code won't go error even if there is no ']' in your string

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SubString` along with the index of the closing bracket, to get what comes after it:

```
foreach (var s in ListBox1.Items)
    {
         s = s.ToString();
         var desc = s.SubString(s.LastIndexOf("]") + 1);
         ListBox2.Items.Add(desc);
    }
```

Comment: Because you are using Listbox1.items you cant choose Substring you only choose tostring,  gethascode, equals, gettype

Comment: Then use `s.ToString().SubString(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use SubString if foreach loop variable datatype is "string". if you define variable as "var" then you must convert the "var" to "string".

try this...

```
foreach (string item in listBox1.Items)
{
    listBox2.Items.Add(item.Substring(item.LastIndexOf("]") + 1));
}
```

Or

```
foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
{
    listBox2.Items.Add(item.ToString().Substring(item.ToString().LastIndexOf("]") + 1));
}
```